# Creating a dict with dictionary comprehension and eval() gives me NameError

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary with dictionary comprehensions in the following way (which is part of a much larger code)

```
columns = ['zeta', 'Lm', 'u_mean']
print('zeta', eval('zeta'))
print(locals())
dic = {col: [eval(col)] for col in columns}
```

The first `print` prints exactly as expected (the value of the variable `zeta`) and the second `print` confirms that `zeta` is in the locals dictionary, but in the dictionary comprehension command python fails with this error

```
NameError: name 'zeta' is not defined
```

Unfortunately, when trying to reproduce to error in order to post here, I found out that I can't reproduce the error, because the following commands work in `ipython`:

```
zeta,Lm,u_mean=1,4,69
columns=['zeta', 'Lm', 'u_mean']
print('zeta',eval('zeta'))
print(locals())
dic={ col : [eval(col)] for col in columns }
```

It is only those commands inside my code that do not work.
So, am I missing something? Is there some test I can do to see what's wrong?

Comment: Technically speaking, you have a *dictionary comprehension*, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension is executed in a *new scope*, a lot like a nested function call. You cannot expect to access the locals of the parent scope in a list comprehension.

I strongly recommend you do not use locals like this. Create a separate dictionary to act as a namespace and look up your columns in that:

```
namespace = {
    'zeta': value_for_zeta,
    # ... etc.
}
```

then use `{col: [namespace[col]] for col in columns}`.

Failing that, you can store the `locals()` dictionary in a new variable and reference that; either directly, or through passing it in as the namespace for `eval()`:

```
namespace = locals()
dic = {col: [eval(col, namespace)] for col in columns}
```

or simply:

```
namespace = locals()
dic = {col: [namespace[col]] for col in columns}
```

This works now because `namespace` is a *closure*; a name taken from the parent scope.

Note that the same limits apply to generator expressions, set comprehensions, and in Python 3, list comprehensions. Python 2 list comprehensions were implemented before all the other types and followed a different implementation strategy that did not involve a new scope, but this approach did not allow for generator expressions to work and the new approach with a separate scope was generally found to work better.